# Styling or formatting json data in xaml

Tags: c#, json, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on an windows phone 8.1 app but as I am a beginner and my background is more towards websites where I write css and the magic works. I am finding it difficult to format the JSON data which gets binded to my xaml.

My JSON code

```
{"Groups":[
  {
    "UniqueId": "BasicxGroup1",
    "Title": "Startup",
    "Subtitle": "test subtitle 1",
    "ImagePath": "Assets/startup1.jpg"
    "Items":
    [
      {
        "UniqueId": "Group-1-Item-1",
        "Title": "Item Title: 1",
        "Subtitle": "Item Subtitle: 1",
        "ImagePath": "Assets/LightGray.png",
        "Description" : "test description",
        "Content" : "test content some formatting needed"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

I can use other option like I might add another key to my group item and then bind it to my xaml and then I can style it individually but just for the sake of formatting is this necessary ? Do I have other option?

My XAML code

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Margin="10,0,10,0" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Description}" />
        </Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Margin="10,0,10,0" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Content}" /></Grid>
        </Grid>
```

I am new to this and I am learning so please point me out if I am wrong in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [RichTextBox](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1861eb96-1a99-4e4c-a3b1-3ac9dfe7ec4b) control.